# Are IoT Hub Device Twin properties secure for things like connecting strings?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am currently thinking about a solution where an IoT device would have more than one possible endpoint to talk to. Like an API for some calls that do not concern telemetry or device twin data.

The connection to the IoT Hub can be secured very well (we will use certificates), and I want to awoid adding a different way of authentication to the architecture.

So my idea right now would be to have a back-end service generate device specific SAS tokens for my APIs, possibly on-demand if requested by the device.

The [Cloud-to-device communications guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-c2d-guidance) mentions configuration data, so it feels like a good way to go. Would it be safe to write these tokens in the desired properties? Would it be safer to use the payload of a cloud-to-device-message? Or should it be done completely differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom cloud service as a token service that uses an IoT Hub shared access policy with DeviceConnect permissions to create device-scoped tokens.

For more detailed information you can reference "[Custom device authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#custom-device-authentication)".

Comment: This would replace the authentication against the IoT Hub with my own, right? I wanted to keep that security and basically use it to securely get tokens for **other** APIs, not the IoT Hub itself

Comment: @AlexAIT If you focus on how to send your tokens to the device not how to generate tokens, D2C message and desired properties both can complete this work. You can have a try.